# jQuery - Using easeOutBounce in animation Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I try to animate a div with a easeOutBounce effect when the page load, but is not working for me.

I have referenced the jQuery UI.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").animate({marginTop: "-=50px"},1000,'easeOutBounce');
});
```

My html code:

```
<div class="content">
    <h3>Titulo h3</h3>
    <p>Este texto lleva una animacion lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nulla urna, consequat nec erat bibendum, ullamcorper fermentum ligula.</p>
    <img width="50%" src="Images/javascript-movimiento.png" alt="animationJS" />
 </div>
```

Comment: I think we are going to need to see some more context for the .content element. You could have something as simple as a typo in the class name, for example.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I add the html code up in the main question || If I don't add 'easeOutBounce', the function works correctly, but if I add this, the function doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Chrome - I see the title and the para, then very quickly the para slides up to the top with a pleasing bounce. Please confirm it works for you too and if so check you HTML for typos.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body >

 <div class="content">
    <h3>Titulo h3</h3>
    <p>Este texto lleva una animacion lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nulla urna, consequat nec erat bibendum, ullamcorper fermentum ligula.</p>
    <img width="50%" src="Images/javascript-movimiento.png" alt="animationJS" />
</div>

</body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".content").animate({marginTop: "-=50px"},1000,'easeOutBounce');
    });
 </script>

 </html>
```

Comment: Now it works! I have asigned a margin-top:50px to 'content' class, this was a problem... but I don't understand why...

Comment: What browser are you seeing this behaviour in?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Maybe there is something different in the rest of your page that was not in the snippet you provided. Did you try my html above? What happens?

Comment: Yes, your html isr working correctly, but this don't work when I assign margin-top:Xpx; on my 'content' class

Comment: Working on MY html, if I assign a `margin-top: 50px;` then the transition will start with a 50px space above the title and then reduce the top margin to zero leaving the title visible. If I wanted to have the final position be that the title was off the top of the page then I would make the transition `-=100px`. Try it.